# Swift: Getting immutable error with mutable Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm getting the error:

Immutable value of type [UIImageView] only has mutating members named 'append'.

With this code:

```
var pageViews:[UIImageView]!;

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad();

    pageViews = [UIImageView]();
    for i in 0 ..< 5
    {
        pageViews.append(UIImageView());
    }
}
```

Why does this happen even though the array is declared with `var`? The error sounds confusing to me.

Comment: I would bet it's a problem with the fact that it's an optional.

Comment: Current workaround - creat a non-optional array, append to it and then assign it to `pageViews`.

Comment: It works if I remove the exclamation mark but then I have to instantiate the array either instantly or in an initialiser but that's not (always) desired.